# Win batch file: renaming all files in a directory with a formatted, incrementing name

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I have a directory containing png files that I need to order from oldest to newest, then rename with a name containing an incrementing numeric suffix that's always 4 digits, e.g. the first file would be 'file_0001.png', the thousandth file would be 'file_1000.png'.

Using bits of code I found by searching online (including some I found on here) I first wrote a batch file containing the following:

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set "count=1"
for /f "delims=*" %%f in ('dir /b /o:d /tc *.png') do (
ren %%f file_!count!.png
set /a count+=1
)
```

This works but the numeric part of the file name isn't formatted as I need it.
I therefore tried to adapt the above by adding another variable which is derived from the incrementing count variable, then only including the 4 digits I need when renaming the file:

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set count=1
for /f "delims=*" %%f in ('dir /b /o:d /tc *.png') do (
set "fcount=000000!%count%"
ren %%f file_!fcount:~-4!.png
set /a count+=1
)
```

When I run this it renames the first file correctly but then I get an error to say that a duplicate file name exists or the file can't be found, so I'm thinking that there must be an issue with line 4 causing it not to increment properly:

```
set "fcount=000000!%count%"
```

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You weren't far away; try this:

```bash
@Echo Off
SetLocal EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion
Set "count=10000"
For /F "EOL=? Delims=" %%G In ('Dir *.png /A:-D /B /O:D /T:C 2^>NUL') Do (
    Set /A count += 1
    Ren "%%G" file_!count:~-4!%%~xG
)
```

Comment: That works perfectly. Thanks a lot!